# Plotting two different values with corresponding date in Pyplot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am currently trying to plot two different values on a line graph with their corresponding date on the X axis.

For each date, I have two values; Bitcoin price data, and a sentiment score.

Here's an example of the data:

| date | compound | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-01 | 0.1601 | 7541.4501953125 |
| 2018-06-02 | 0.3049 | 7643.4501953125 |
| 2018-06-03 | 0.296 | 7720.25 |
| 2018-06-04 | 0.266 | 7514.47021484375 |
| 2018-06-05 | 0.2533 | 7633.759765625 |
| 2018-06-06 | 0.2295 | 7653.97998046875 |

This is getting close to what I would like:
Line graph but dates are wrong

[image]

I'm very new to programming in general so realise my code will be very messy/inefficient, but here is what I have used so far to get the above result:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Bitcoin Price (US Dollar)', color=color)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=15))
plt.plot(tweets_normal.date,tweets_normal.price, color=color)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('Bitcoin Tweet Sentiment', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(tweets_normal.compound, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.title('Bitcoin price vs Bitcoin Tweet Sentiment')
fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

Any help get the dates correct would be hugely appreciated! No idea where the 1970's came from

Comment: in the second axis `ax2.plot(tweets_normal.compound, color=color)`, you did not provide, the input for x axis which should be `tweets_normal.date` in your case.Assuming that's where your dates are stored. Try this and check `ax2.plot(tweets_normal.date,tweets_normal.compound, color=color)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment :)

Unfortunately the dates looked all squished together so I'm unsure if the dates are actually correct or not - [link](https://imgur.com/W02ihFO)

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't look like `'date'` is a datetime format: [this is how to plot a dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uTZI.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if `date` data are stored as `datetime` type or `str` type, so have a look to `tweets_normal.info()`. You will get something like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------    --------------  -----  
 0   date      6 non-null      object 
 1   compound  6 non-null      float64
 2   price     6 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 272.0+ bytes
None
```

Pay attention to `date` `Dtype`: if it is `object` (so it is `str`), then you need to convert it to `datetime` with:

```
tweets_normal.date = pd.to_datetime(tweets_normal.date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now you should have:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   date      6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   compound  6 non-null      float64       
 2   price     6 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2)
memory usage: 272.0 bytes
None
```

So you are ready to draw the plot.
It is important to specify to matplolitb your x axis is a date type, as you correctly already did, with:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=15))
```

Finally, you have to specify x and y axis for both `ax` and `ax2` (as already reported by Shubham Shaswat in the comment of the question):

```
plt.plot(tweets_normal.date,tweets_normal.price, color=color)
```

and

```
ax2.plot(tweets_normal.date,tweets_normal.compound, color=color)
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


tweets_normal = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')
tweets_normal.date = pd.to_datetime(tweets_normal.date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('Bitcoin Price (US Dollar)', color=color)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=15))
plt.plot(tweets_normal.date,tweets_normal.price, color=color)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('Bitcoin Tweet Sentiment', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(tweets_normal.date,tweets_normal.compound, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.title('Bitcoin price vs Bitcoin Tweet Sentiment')
fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

[image]